# How can I check for the current path in bash?

Tags: bash

## I'm working

on multiple projects : A, B, C, D, E and F.
I go though all my projects via **Terminal**, and swapping between them via **Terminal Tabs**.

Sometimes, I confuse between projects because they have the **same** text color, in this case is yellow.

[image]

---

## I'm trying

to achieve something like this:

[image]

I would like to assign a different color base on the current path of the project.

How to do I check for current path in bash ?

---

## .bash_profile

```
#================================
#            Colors             =
#================================

black="\[\033[0;30m\]"
blue="\[\033[1;37m\]"
green="\[\033[0;32m\]"
cyan="\[\033[0;36m\]"
red="\[\033[0;31m\]"
purple="\[\033[0;35m\]"
brown="\[\033[0;33m\]"
lightgray="\[\033[0;37m\]"
darkgray="\[\033[1;30m\]"
lightblue="\[\033[1;34m\]"
lightgreen="\[\033[1;32m\]"
lightcyan="\[\033[1;36m\]"
lightred="\[\033[1;31m\]"
lightpurple="\[\033[1;35m\]"
yellow="\[\033[1;33m\]"
white="\[\033[1;37m\]"
nc="\[\033[0m\]"

if [ "\w" == "~/dev/projects/biv2" ]; then
  export PS1="──$white[$blue\w$white] \n└── $white"
fi

// Default Color
export PS1="──$white[$yellow\w$white] \n└── $white"
```

Comment: `\w` is not a variable; it's just a macro that is expanded by the shell when displaying one of the prompts.

Comment: Can you please help me resolve this ? Thanks in advance. I'm new to bash.

Comment: Working up an answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use `PROMPT_COMMAND` to check what the current directory is just before displaying the prompt, and set the value of `PS1` accordingly.

```
prompt_cmd () {
    case $PWD in
        ~/dev/projects/biv2) dircolor=$yellow ;;
        ~/dev/projects/other) dircolor=$blue ;;
        # and so on. For any other directory,
        *) dircolor=$green
    esac
    PS1="──$white[$dircolor\w$white] \n└── $white"
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_cmd
```

---

Without `PROMPT_COMMAND`, you could do something like

```
set_dir_color () {
    case $PWD in
        ~/dev/projects/biv2) dircolor=$yellow ;;
        ~/dev/projects/other) dircolor=$blue ;;
        # and so on. For any other directory,
        *) dircolor=$green
    esac
    echo "$dircolor"
}

PS1="──$white[\$(set_dir_color)\w$white] \n└── $white"
```

Comment: Wow.. Impressive. I'm testing it out now. I will make sure to accept it if it works. ! Thanks.

Comment: Lastly, you said I have to use `PROMPT_COMMAND`, just out of curiosity, where do we get that from ?

Comment: Do you need `PROMPT_COMMAND` for this or could you just embed that function call inside `PS1` directly? I would assume `PS1` is evaluated in the context of the working directory (but maybe not).

Comment: You probably could, but I really dislike embedding code in `PS1`.